# Is there a difference in performance between LTRIM(RTRIM(column_name)) and RTRIM(LTRIM(column_name))

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, where-clause

When trimming both ends of a string in SQL Server, is there a performance difference, or any other reason to prefer nesting the `LTRIM` versus the `RTRIM` function when building a where clause?

For example:

```
WHERE RTRIM(LTRIM(SalesPerson)) <> ''
```

Comment: Why not write a bunch of queries using either or and set a timer on that and see?

Comment: I'm not sure about t-sql, however in something like mysql using InnoDB, a value tree is built that handles things like constants, and then performs on more complicated structures. Think of it sort of like a weighted graph, the path with the "shortest" execution and logical structures is chosen. I would bet that the difference between these 2 is so negligible that even a micro timer would not see the difference.

Comment: You can study more about this by doing research on logical transformations. :-)

Comment: Just use TRIM(val) instead of RTRIM(LTRIM(val)) --> http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ee634558.aspx

Comment: What data type is your column?

Comment: In this case the datatype is varchar, but I was thinking in more general terms (i.e. including nvarchar).

Comment: Have you tried your query without rtrim/ltrim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query can be replaced with:

```
WHERE SalesPerson <> ''
```

Even when there are spaces in '' the check will give the same result. Trimming in this case gives no meaning, and will probably slow your query, since you are comparing with a calculation on the column.

Reversing Ltrim and Rtrim should give no performance difference.

Comment: Does this mean you would not be able to query for a truly empty string if the results include strings with whitespace?

Comment: @Feckmore sure you can, if you use like: WHERE '' like ' ' will check false.: WHERE '' = ' ' will check true